# Mechanic damaged the inside of my runflats

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

So as the title says, I'm not sure what was going through that mechanic's mind but they tore into the side of three of my tires to varying degrees, I can see the metal from the inside. I doubt that this is safe however they insist that it's safe, that they wouldn't hesitate to drive on a tire like that if their kid was in the car, and that the best they'll as compensation is to install them for me. They didn't tell me the tires had been damaged and insist this is perfectly normal for run flat tires... Any input on this I call BS on the mechanic as it neither looks normal, safe, nor does it look like it will hold air that well...

Thanks for any input

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I don't really know for sure concerning run-flats, my initial reaction is *I don't take my tires to a tire shop to get them damaged* run-flat or not. I'll let someone who has actually dealt with them let you know. I'd be looking for the shop to buy you new tires. Run-flats are definitely NOT CHEAP ... Like I have to say this to you!

Answer (score 2):

Horsefeathers!  Perfectly normal?  Not a chance.

Run flats are a royal pain to mount and dismount.  Without the proper tire change machine and training, damage is a real possibility.

How much you want to pursue this is up to you.  You can certainly contact the tire manufacturer for a statement that will completely rebuke these asinine claims, but unless you are willing to endure a protracted legal battle, you may not have many options for recovery.  And whatever you decide, I would certainly be incredibly reluctant to give them a "second chance" to obtain competency and honesty overnight.

If it's a local independent, it will be tough.  If it's a franchise or part of a larger chain, you may be able to appeal to the governing company.

To specifically answer your question, it's NOT safe, it's NOT correct, and it's NOT normal.

You are owed new tires and a competent installation.

How did you discover the problems?  Why were the tires removed?  Did they deliver them mounted, or called you in to take a look at the carnage?  Were the tires leaking air?  Just curious - my answer doesn't change.

Better Luck!

Comment: I agree completely, I wouldn't drive on those alone, much less with my precious progeny in the back! @TiredOfTires, if you paid on a credit card then call the credit card company and put a stop payment on it. Document the damage thoroughly and in writing. If you haven't paid yet then don't!

Comment: @GdD now that's smart; I hadn't thought of that.  CC companies almost always side with the cardholder, if you have your "ducks in a row".

Comment: I have unfortunately had to use this more than once and I got my money back every time @SteveRacer. As you say you have to document it thoroughly.